# Running performance test on machine with varying loads

Tags: java, performance, testing

I have a test in my JUnit suite which warns me about a performance drop. The test works along these lines: Usually, I can run 100'000 operations per second, but the load on the build server can vary, so I'm happy with anything > 25'000.

Today, the build failed with 24'300 ops/s. When I ran the test with Java 7 (rc1, debug flavor), I got 5'000 ops/s. The former would be OK, the latter is a red flag that the test must catch.

Now the simple solution would be to reduce my goal to 20'000 but I was wondering if there was a better way to define the "safe range" of performance test if the machine can be under load.

Comment: Can't you just vary the threshold based on the load average of the server?

Comment: Yes, but how exactly would I do that?

Comment: Get the output of `uptime` (Linux) or an equivalent, depending on what platform your build server is running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than measure wall-clock time, measure CPU time via the [ThreadMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html). If you're looking to support 50k ops/second, then each operation should take < 20,000 nanoseconds.

I don't know if the garbage collector threads will be accessible through this bean. If not, you will need to get their execution times via the [GarbageCollectorMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would run the test more than once (e.g. take 11 results and check the median, which ignore sudden dips in performance), or over a longer period of time so you can get more consistent results. If you cannot control the load of the server, you can get the load on unix boxes and take this into account when determining a reasonable range.

Answer (score 1):

The pure ops/s figure is meaningless in isolation. If the load on the machine can cause a 5 fold variance (100k down to 20k) then I you can surely be masking quite significant changes in your application's behaviour.

I think your philosophy of repeatedly test for performance change is a commendable idea but I just don't see how to implement this unless you have a reliable platform.

I guess you could attempt to measure the overall platform utilisation and adjust your test results accordingly but a reliable model would surely take quite a bit of developing.